# C programming. If I am using fgets(line, MAXLINE, stdin) function in a loop, should I zero-out line each time before a new iteration?

Tags: c

If I am using fgets(line, MAXLINE, stdin) function in a loop, should I zero-out line each time before a new iteration? Meaning is I have smth like

```
char *line = calloc(MAXLINE+1, 1);
    while (fgets(line, MAXLINE+1, stdin)) {
        ...
    }
```

is it required to reallocate or zero-out the line char string before next call of fgets?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  `fgets` guarantees zero termination on a successful read.  Your loop condition handles the unsuccessful case.  For completeness, you should check that the calloc worked though.

Comment: I think OP's `zero-out` mean `fill memory with 0's`.

Comment: Yes - when working with strings though the reason to do that is to guard against missing terminators.  Not needed here.